# How set headers response cakephp in async request

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp-2.0

I development an application with cakephp2 and angularjs.

The problem is when i have a exception, i can not try/catch block.

Somebody help?

Thanks! Sorry my English.

Cheers!

Comment: title of question and question description, both seems very different.

Comment: I wanna set the code of response when i have a exception, try/catch block 
they do not work